# Regex positive lookbehind including all words preceded by word

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm using the `stringr` package in R and would like to replace all values that follow the word ***except*** with the word ***MATCH***. I'm getting an error that states *' . . . must have a bounded maximum length (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)'*. Here is my code that throws the error:

```
strings <- c(" wholesale trade  except motor vehicles motorcycles",
             " retail trade  except motor vehicles motorcycles") 


str_replace_all(strings,'(?<=\\bexcept\\W+)\\w+','MATCH')
```

My desired output is:

```
> strings
[1] " wholesale trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
[2] " retail trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
```

Note, some strings will have many more ***MATCH***'s to replace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a base R solution with `gsub`:

```
strings <- c(" wholesale trade  except motor vehicles motorcycles",
             " retail trade  except motor vehicles motorcycles") 
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)\\s+|\\bexcept\\s+)\\K\\w+", "MATCH", strings, perl=TRUE)
# [1] " wholesale trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
# [2] " retail trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
```

See the [R demo](http://rextester.com/RNHB11109).

A `stringr` equivalent can be

```
> str_replace_all(strings, "(\\G(?!^)\\s+|\\bexcept\\s+)\\w+", "\\1MATCH")
[1] " wholesale trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
[2] " retail trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
```

Basically, the pattern is

```
(?:\G(?!^)\s+|\bexcept\s+)\K\w+
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k1QPxy/1/).

The `\w` may be replaced with `\S` if you want to match any chunks of non-whitespace chars.

**Pattern details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)\s+|\bexcept\s+)` - match a whole word `except` and any 1+ whitespace chars after it (`\bexcept\s+`) or (`|`) the end of the previous match with 1+ whitespace chars after (`\G(?!^)\s+`)
- `\K` - clears the match value
- `\w+` - matches 1+ word chars (`\S+`) will match any 1 or more non-whitespace chars)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one with `base R` where split the string at 'except' replace the words in the second elements with 'MATCH" and `paste` it with first

```
sapply(strsplit(strings, "\\bexcept\\s+"), 
     function(x) paste0(x[1], "except ", gsub("\\w+", "MATCH", x[2])))
#[1] " wholesale trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH" 
#[2] " retail trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `gsubfn` to extract the `except...` part and process that with the anonymous function (expressed in formula notation).  That function accepts two arguments `x` and `y` whose values are the two capture groups, i.e. the two parenthesized expressions in the regular expression.  The first argument `x` will be passed as `except` followed by trailing space or spaces and the second `y` is the remainder of the string.  (It determines the names and number of arguments by scanning the body of the function, i.e. the right hand side of the formula, and extracting the free variables.) It then uses `gsub` to replace each word in `y` with `MATCH`.  In the regular regular expressions `\s` matches space and `\S` matches non-space.  `.*` matches everything from that point on.  It retains the original spacing and uses only relatively simple regular expressions.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("( except\\s+)(.*)", ~ paste0(x, gsub("\\S+", "MATCH", y)), strings)
## [1] " wholesale trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH" " retail trade  except MATCH MATCH MATCH"
```